# concurrent mySql database queries

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I'm running mySql server that being updated every 4 hours.
In the mean while data can be retrieved.

Does mySql handle this scenario where the DB is being updated
and a query from the user is received?

or I should handle this scenario?
Is it possible to create a snapshot of the DB just before the update takes place 
and query this DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about how concurrent writes are handled, that's one thing, but you can safely read from a MySQL database that is being updated by another thread without worrying about corrupted data.

Of course, if the writing thread is performing multiple writes that need to be atomic (ie all or none), make sure he is using a transaction.

Comment: only 1 writing thread is available which takes place every 4 hours.
The writing thread pulls all records from the DB.
for each record: it does some task and updates the record with the new received data.

so there is a possibility where record i is being updated and the user who owns record i tries to get data from it.
so I'll read more about transaction. 

Is it possible to split the work between separated threads in PHP?
I mean the task for each record takes like 10 sec and for performances issues I though to split the work.

Comment: "so there is a possibility where record i is being updated and the user who owns record i tries to get data from it." - this shouldn't pose you any problem.  Assuming you are using a transaction to write the data, the user is either going to see the view of the database before the update or after it, depending on the order in which the queries were received.  If the read comes in followed by the write, you can't tell the database to hold off on the read until the write is done, but you shouldn't need to because the user is getting a valid view of the data.

Comment: Re: PHP threads, there are no such thing.  You will need to fork multiple processes.  See http://www.alternateinterior.com/2007/05/multi-threading-strategies-in-php.html for an example.

Comment: So I should combine all writings to 1 transaction?
if the read comes before the write transaction thats fine the user gets the up to date data.
on the other hand if the read comes after the write transaction the user could get the data from the DB or the DB is locked until the write transaction is done?

Other issue is that the write transaction could take some time and let say the record i was updated but still by using transaction the user won't get the updated data.
how do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use transactions and/or locking to make sure that every user sees a consistent view (i.e. completely updated or not updated at all). The database engine itself is very well suited to the scenario. If you are not worried about what readers see at the exact time the updates are running, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Considering my scenario I think that no further actions are required.
If the write comes before the read the user will get the most updated data
otherwise it does not, and he will wait for next query.

This fits my requirements.

Thank you all

Comment: If any posted answers to this thread helped you reach your conclusion, it is generally polite to upvote and / or accept them.  This also helps other readers find useful information.